# JavaScript: regex extract variables

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract just field names from some JavaScript code, everything before the equals sign but ignoring IF statements etc.

I can get it to work for the IF statement but not for something that follows the equals sign.

Any help would be most appreciated.

This is what I have so far.

The trouble is on the 3rd line where I only want the field **validator** and not the string contained in the ()

```
^((?!if).+)(?==)
```

**ruleMode =** "test";

*if(ruleMode == "test")*

**validator = (percent >= margin.lower) && (percent <=** margin.upper);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression will work if you add `\s` allowing whitespace before your equal sign. Your desired matches are now captured in capture group `#1`. See [working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xO7kE8) of your regex after allowing whitespace.

```
^((?!if).+)(?=\s=)
```

I would probably use a non-capturing group here and place your quantifier `+` outside if you go this route.

Or if the value before the `=` sign is always alphanumeric, you could just match with `\w`, and ignore the double `==`

```
(\w+)(?= +=[^=])
```

Or the opposite negating non-word characters.

```
([^\W]+)(?= +=[^=])
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/mR5jX7)

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check the following regular expression:

```
(\w+)(?=\s*=[^=])
```

It will check for words that are followed by a `=` that is not followed by another `=`. Sign words, it will match all variable names that are being assigned.

Here you can see a demo of your code, and some other code: http://regex101.com/r/fM9hL2

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I hope this is what you want.